# GMSPlacesClient currentPlaceWithCallback: takes too much time

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

I'm using Google places api for iOS.I've implemented current place feature. Here's the code(it's same as google provided in guide).

```
[_placesClient currentPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlaceLikelihoodList *likelihoodList, NSError *error) {
  if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Current Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return;
  }

  for (GMSPlaceLikelihood *likelihood in likelihoodList.likelihoods) {
    GMSPlace* place = likelihood.place;
    NSLog(@"Current Place name %@ at likelihood %g", place.name, likelihood.likelihood);
    NSLog(@"Current Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
    NSLog(@"Current Place attributions %@", place.attributions);
    NSLog(@"Current PlaceID %@", place.placeID);
  }

}];
```

but it takes about 3-4 minutes to execute the callback. I've followed all the steps they provided in guide.

Comment: its a bad quesition for me to ask but still, are you using a device or running it in simulator?

Comment: try it in simulator and please share your result.

Comment: @SahebRoy I have a similar problem. The device is taking about a minute to find the location but on simulator its quick (less than 5 secs)

Comment: Well its maybe coz of the network(internet) speed, as it may take time to retrieve location via Google API's if the internet speed is slow. Try in another device, if you can